# Unable to get output from infinitely running Ruby application spawned from Node child process

Tags: node.js, ruby, electron, child-process

I am trying to write a GUI with Node and Electron around an existing ruby command line application. I found an example how to get output from a child process by doing something like:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('node', ['child.js']);

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
```

And the child.js looks like this

```
while(true) {
  console.log('blah');
}
```

This is working fine for me, but if I try and do this with a ruby application switching to this

```
var child = spawn('ruby', ['test.rb']);
```

and this being the ruby code

```
while true
    sleep 2
    puts 'test'
end
```

I get no output. It seems to hang on the output. I would expect to see 'test' printed every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby doesn't know you want the output right away, and buffers it for efficiency. If you make it flush the output buffer ([`IO#flush`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-flush)), it works.

```
while true
    sleep 2
    puts 'test'
    STDOUT.flush
end
```

Alternately, you can tell Ruby you want all output right away ([`IO#sync=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D)):

```
STDOUT.sync = true
while true
    sleep 2
    puts 'test'
end
```

Incidentally, your original code works on JRuby, so the buffering behaviour differs... I did not know that...

Comment: Thanks. That was it.